# alternative method instead $watch in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope variable, when it returns true, i need to trigger some events or do something. I my case, the every first time, the scope variable returns undefined and later it returns true. In this case i used $watch method to get the expected funcionality. Is there any alternative approach to do the same instead using $watch ?

```
 scope.$watch () ->
    scope.initiateChild
  , (value) ->
    if value is true
      $timeout ->
        scope.buildOnboarding()
      , 1000
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would not want to use `$watch`?

Comment: `$watch` seems to do *exactly* what you are asking for, do you want an alias for `$watch` or something?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using AngularJS **$on()**, **$emit()** and **$broadcast()**.

Here is an example: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx

Comment: @AryehBeitz thanks for reporting. Replaced it with another useful article.

Comment: $on(), $emit() and $broadcast()- which one is the best and fast ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript getters and setters without any expense of using $watch.
Write code in the setter to do what you want when angular changes the your model's value you are using in scope. It gets null or an a State object as user types. Useful for working with type ahead text boxes that have dependencies on each other. Like list of counties after typing state without user selecting anything.

Here is some pseudo style code to get the idea.

```
      <input ng-model="searchStuff.stateSearchText" />
      <div>{{searchStuff.stateObject.counties.length}}</div>
      <div>{{searchStuff.stateObject.population}}</div>

        $scope.searchStuff=new function(){var me=this;};
        $scope.searchStuff.stateObject = null;

        $scope.searchStuff.getStateObjectFromSearchText = function(search){
        // get set object from search then
           return stateObject;
        };

        $scope.searchStuff._stateSearchText= "";
        Object.defineProperty($scope.searchStuff, 'stateSearchText', {
            get: function () {
                return me._stateSearchText;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                me,_stateSearchText = value;
                me.stateObject = getStateObjectFromSearchText (value);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

Also watch the following video: [Communicating Between Controllers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw)

A sample example is given below

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerZero">
  <input ng-model="message" >
  <button ng-click="handleClick(message);">LOG</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
  <input ng-model="message" >
</div>

<div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
  <input ng-model="message" >
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
  var sharedService = {};

  sharedService.message = '';

  sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.broadcastItem();
  };

  sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
  };

  return sharedService;
});

function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(msg);
  };

  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.message = sharedService.message;
  });        
}

function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + sharedService.message;
  });        
}

function ControllerTwo($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.message = 'TWO: ' + sharedService.message;
  });
}

ControllerZero.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];        

ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];

ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```